# One-hot encoding to embedded vector - BigGAN

Tags: tensorflow, gan, embeddings

I am trying to [replicate a BigGAN architecture in Tensorflow](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1809.11096.pdf) but fail to understand exact nature of inputs.
BigGAN generator has 2 inputs, noise `z` that is a vector of `[batch size, 120]` elements drawn from normal distribution and vector `Embedded(y)` that is of size `[batch size,128]`, where `y` is a vector of class labels. [image: BigGAN architecture 128x128]
By looking at [tfhub](https://tfhub.dev/deepmind/biggan-128/2) code example

```
# Load BigGAN 128 module.
module = hub.Module('https://tfhub.dev/deepmind/biggan-128/2')

# Sample random noise (z) and ImageNet label (y) inputs.
batch_size = 8
truncation = 0.5  # scalar truncation value in [0.02, 1.0]
z = truncation * tf.random.truncated_normal([batch_size, 120])  # noise sample
y_index = tf.random.uniform([batch_size], maxval=1000, dtype=tf.int32)
y = tf.one_hot(y_index, 1000)  # one-hot ImageNet label

# Call BigGAN on a dict of the inputs to generate a batch of images with shape
# [8, 128, 128, 3] and range [-1, 1].
samples = module(dict(y=y, z=z, truncation=truncation))
```

my understanding is that `y` is a one-hot form and `Embedded(y)` is a mapping of these class labels.

1. What kind of functions is it?
2. How can I encode all possible classes to such embedding?
3. Is it equivalent to  `tf.keras.layers.Embedding` (see [here](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/keras/layers/Embedding))?version=stable ?
4. If yes, can it be implemented in tensorflow as explained [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34877590/2710943)?